# Changing the colour scheme in ggplot and being able to edit legends

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the colour scheme in ggplot in addition to tweaking the legend. However, I only seem to be able to do one of these, with the most recent command overwriting the other.

I've got an MWE here, so this just creates a dummy plot with a custom legend with multiple words in my legend title and factor variables.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(17)
df <- data.frame(method=sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 20, replace=T),
             score=runif(20),
             group=sample(0:1, 20, replace=T))
ggplot(df, aes(x=method, y=score, fill=factor(group))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_discrete("Multi word title", breaks=c(0, 1), labels=c('Group 1', 'Group 2'))
```

[image: Initial image]

Then I obtained the following nice colour scheme (from [here](http://rpubs.com/Koundy/71792)) which I wanted to use with the above plot.

```
library(scales)
scale_fill_Publication <- function(...){
  discrete_scale("fill","Publication",manual_pal(values = c("#386cb0","#fdb462","#7fc97f","#ef3b2c","#662506","#a6cee3","#fb9a99","#984ea3","#ffff33")), ...)
}
```

However, when I combine this with the plotting code I get a warning *Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale.*

And it's clear to see from the resulting plot that this latest instruction has overwritten the legend modification. I could change the factor names in the data frame but this doesn't work well for words separated with a space.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=method, y=score, fill=factor(group))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_discrete("Multi word title", breaks=c(0, 1), 
                      labels=c('Group 1', 'Group 2')) +
  scale_fill_Publication()
```

[image: Incorrect image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just one fill scale. Put the labels and title inside your defined scale, it uses the same arguments as other scales.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=method, y=score, fill=factor(group))) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      scale_fill_Publication("Multi word title", breaks=c(0, 1), 
                          labels=c('Group 1', 'Group 2'))
```

Comment: What happened to the colour specifications in the answer?